# How to set ImageView border solid?

Tags: android, imageview, border, android-styles

I have an imageView in xml which I want to set its border to solid 1px black. I looked at several codes, but none work. And the code is not very well explained. Could someone help
Thanks

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aristoteles_imageview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aristoteles"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

**create border.xml in drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"></stroke>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

---

**then set background in imageView and set padding 3dp**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aristoteles_imageview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aristoteles"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>
```